# How do you configure JayData to send POST/PUT instead of MERGE/PATCH

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, odata, kendo-grid, jaydata

I'm using a KendoUI grid to display some data. I'm using JayData to simplify the CRUD operations.

When I edit one item in a row and then click on update, it sends a MERGE Verb instead of POST.

Right now, I only want to send POST instead of MERGES.

How do I configure JayData to send PUTs and POSTs instead of MERGEs and PATCHes.

I don't think it matters, but below is my code:

```
var baseAssetMgmtURL = "http://localhost/AssetManagementAPI/odata/";
var crudServiceComputerBaseURL = baseAssetMgmtURL + "Computers/";

var computer = $data.define("computer", {
   ComputerId: { type: Number, key: true },
   AssetTag: Number,
   BrandModel: String,
   ComputerModelTypeId: Number,
   ComputerTypeId: Number,
   ComputerType: String,
   PurchaseDate: Date,
   OperatingSystemTypeId: Number,
   OperatingSystemType: String,
   ComputerName: String,
   Notes: String,
   MHIPSConnection: Date,
   RetiredDate: Date
});

var ds = computer.asKendoDataSource({
   provider: 'oData',
   url: crudServiceComputerBaseURL,
   batch: false,
   pageSize: 10,
   serverPaging: false
   //,
   //transport: { update: { type: "POST" } }
});

var setGrid = function () {
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    columns: [
        { title: "AssetTag", field: "AssetTag", filterable: false },
        {
            title: "Brand Type", field: "ComputerModelTypeId", filterable: false,
            editor: brandTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#= getModelType(ComputerModelTypeId) #"
        },
        {
            title: "Computer Type", field: "ComputerTypeId", filterable: false,
            editor: computerTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#= getComputerType(ComputerTypeId) #"
        },
        { title: "PurchaseDate", field: "PurchaseDate", filterable: false },
        {
            title: "OS Type", field: "OperatingSystemTypeId", filterable: false,
            editor: osTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#= getOSType(OperatingSystemTypeId) #"
        },
        { title: "Name", field: "ComputerName", filterable: false },
        { title: "Notes", field: "Notes", filterable: false },
        { title: "MHIPSConnection", field: "MHIPSConnection", filterable: false },
        { title: "Retired", field: "RetiredDate", filterable: false },
        { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;" }
    ],
    pageable: true,
    sortable: false,
    scrollable: false,
    editable: "inline",
    toolbar: ["create"]
});
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the http verb to put/post but the body of the request would still be a merge request, you can find examples about rewriting here: https://github.com/jaydata/jaydata/issues/111

if you want REST then use the webapi provider